# How can multiple ASP.NET requests with same session can be executed concurrently by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windbg, session-state, freeze

An ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application freezes from times to times on our production environment.
While trying to analyze the issue using Windbg (+ SOS, SOSEX, NETEXT & MEX) and two production process memory dumps, I noticed that the issue always appears when two requests are being processed concurrently (.NET business code is being executed) for the SAME session. From what I thought I knew, this is not possible without customizing the session behavior (Using config, attributes or ControllerFactory). Sessions are (over)used in this application and the session behavior has not been customized. The only setting I can find (controllers/code/config) is this one in web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="720" />
```

Here are the results of my windbg session if someone can help me understand this case.

!whttp

```
HttpContext    Thread Time Out Running  Status Verb     Url
0000002d0c7754b0   26 00:01:50 00:36:55    200 POST     /Ctrl/Action
0000002e06a2e7e8   27 00:01:50 00:41:45    200 POST     /Ctrl/Action
[...]
```

These are the two HTTP requests taking forever.

!DumpAspNetSession -ctx 0000002d0c7754b0

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer: 0x0000002d0c7a9a38
Key                              Value
================================ ======================================================
VarSession                       0000002e06587000 (App.VarSession)
```

!DumpAspNetSession -ctx 0000002e06a2e7e8

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer: 0x0000002e06a3a810
Key                              Value
================================ ======================================================
VarSession                       0000002e06587000 (App.VarSession)
```

The sessions matching the HttpContext above hold the same Data (App.VarSession type).

!wcookie

```
0000002d0c7754b0 /Ctrl/Action (200 NULL) Running (00:36:55)
======================================================================================
ASP.NET_SessionId=im3clvnd0auw0te3nkzzq1p0

======================================================================================
0000002e06a2e7e8 /Ctrl/Action (200 NULL) Running (00:41:45)
======================================================================================
ASP.NET_SessionId=im3clvnd0auw0te3nkzzq1p0
```

This latest command shows the two requests are indeed related to the same session.

~26s

0:026> !CLRStack

```
OS Thread Id: 0x122c (26)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000002f2de47750 00007ff91a2042db System.Linq.Enumerable+d__14`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()
0000002f2de477b0 00007ff91a2095b7 System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Func`2)
0000002f2de47810 00007ff8be3ce1fe App.DALApp.GetData(...)
```

~27s

0:027> !CLRStack

```
OS Thread Id: 0x313c (27)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000002f2f976f20 00007ff8be5022ef App.DALApp.b__257(...) 
0000002f2f976f60 00007ff91a2042ab System.Linq.Enumerable+d__14`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()
0000002f2f976fc0 00007ff91a2095b7 System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Func`2)
0000002f2f977020 00007ff8be501038 App.DALApp.GetSomeData(...)
```

Both requests are executing custom code (in fact, they use 100% CPU and never end...)

Should this case be possible ? If so, under which conditions and what have I misunderstood regarding session state locking behvior ? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatebehavior?view=netframework-4.0)
Could this weird behavior be the cause of the application hang ?

Thank you.

EDIT: After reading some ASP.NET Code, I have dumped the two HttpContext and it confirms the weird behavior (two requests with **required** session state behavior and **same session** at once). Is there anything I misunderstood ? I cannot believe such a bug could exist without anyone knowing (I cannot find any similar issue on the Web) :

!wdo 0000002E06A2E7E8

```
Address: 0000002e06a2e7e8
Method Table/Token: 00007ff919304a98/20003a304 
Class Name: System.Web.HttpContext
...
00007ff919346278         System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBeha +0164    _SessionStateBehavior_k__BackingField 0 (0n0) Default
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0175         _requiresSessionStateFromHandler 1 (True)
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0176         _readOnlySessionStateFromHandler 0 (False)
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0177                          InAspCompatMode 0 (False)
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0179            _FirstRequest_k__BackingField 0 (False)
00007ff91bbb7af8                                  System.DateTime +0180                            _utcTimestamp -mt 00007FF91BBB7AF8 0000002E06A2E970 28/02/2020 08:16:37
```

!wdo 0000002D0C7754B0

```
Address: 0000002d0c7754b0
Method Table/Token: 00007ff919304a98/20003a304 
Class Name: System.Web.HttpContext
...
00007ff919346278         System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBeha +0164    _SessionStateBehavior_k__BackingField 0 (0n0) Default
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0175         _requiresSessionStateFromHandler 1 (True)
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0176         _readOnlySessionStateFromHandler 0 (False)
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0177                          InAspCompatMode 0 (False)
00007ff91bb9f370                                   System.Boolean +0179            _FirstRequest_k__BackingField 0 (False)
00007ff91bbb7af8                                  System.DateTime +0180                            _utcTimestamp -mt 00007FF91BBB7AF8 0000002D0C775638 28/02/2020 08:21:27
```

EDIT 2: Also asked question on ASP.NET MVC forums : [https://forums.asp.net/t/2169038.aspx?Multiple+concurrent+ASP+NET+MVC+4+requests+for+same+session+possible+without+specific+setting+](https://forums.asp.net/t/2169038.aspx?Multiple%20concurrent%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%204%20requests%20for%20same%20session%20possible%20without%20specific%20setting%20)

Comment: Could your `App.DALApp` be returning a non-thread-safe, cached collection that both threads are iterating over?  Maybe that's causing an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have already checked this and I cannot find a way these collections could be referenced by multiple threads. They are recreated from DB during each thread calsl. I will double check anyway. I am still surprised by these both thread executing concurrently for the same session...

Comment: In fact, I think you were right. Some code is iterating like this : `collection.SelectMany(c => things).SelectMany(t => things2).SelectMany(t2 => things3)` (inside GetData() methods). I have found that t2.Things3 are always different List<> instances on different threads BUT they sometimes contain the same _items array reference. I am not sure how it is possible (?) but I guess I am on the right track.

Comment: The List<T>._items shared instance I was referring to is in fact the List<T> private singleton (static) emptyArray... My issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Regarding the hang, I inspected objects references being enumerated (all of them from root to current item) and cannot find any shared reference between both threads. (The thread 27 stack trace gives the current item)

Comment: About the application hangs. Inspecting the details of the process shows it manipulate A LOT of data leading to nested loops/Linq with a cumulated iterations count greater than 50 billion... So this is not a hang but a REALLY too heavy process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the answer to my own question.
The HttpRuntime executionTimeout setting (default to 110 seconds for ASP.NET 2+) controls the maximum request thread duration AND the session state lock duration. So, after 110 second of processing, it possible for another request from the same session to be processed since the session lock has been released. In my case, as stated by @user2116910 in the SO link below, the first request processing thread is never killed (maybe due to the fact that the application has been deployed using debug config ! :-/)

References:

- https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/858026
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#long
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084159/4627054